# How to put counter inside TextInputLayout (for full-width text fields)?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, material-design

There are full width text fields in Material Design guidelines, but there appears to be no guides or any info about their implementation. In my layout I have two `EditTextLayout`s: single-line and multi-line ones. I've implemented counters using `app:counterEnabled="true"` and `app:counterMaxLength="50"` tags, but they are outside the text fields, which shouldn't happen in case of full width fields. Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: Material Design full width input fields]
And here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_textfield"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterOverflowTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.EditTextOverflow"
        app:counterMaxLength="50">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/fragment_suggestion_input_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:minHeight="?listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="?listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingStart="?listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingRight="?listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
            android:paddingEnd="?listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
            android:hint="Title"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterOverflowTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.EditTextOverflow"
        app:counterMaxLength="400">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/fragment_suggestion_input_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:minHeight="?listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="?listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingStart="?listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingRight="?listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
            android:paddingEnd="?listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
            android:hint="Description"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is what I've got so far: [image: My screenshot]

I believe it is possible make them appear only on focus, using listeners and some code, but I don't know how can I affect their position.

So, my question: how can I make counters appear inside TextInputLayouts, **not outside**?

Comment: How did you manage to do this?

Comment: @AntonShkurenko `app:counterEnabled="true"` and `app:counterMaxLength="400"` inside `TextInputLayout`

Comment: And it will be inside the textview when it's singleLine?

Comment: @AntonShkurenko no, it won't. To put it inside, you have to use additional libraries or make a custom counter.

Comment: well, ok, that's sad

Comment: Try moving the padding attributes from the TextInputEditText tag to the TextInputLayout tag maybe? This solved my issue to an extent.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `setCounterEnabled(boolean)` method that you can use to enable the character counter.

It displays the current character count inside the view.

If you need more description:

> ```
> android.support.design:counterEnabled
> ```
>
> Whether the layout is laid out as if the character counter will be
>   displayed
>
> Must be a `boolean` value, either `true` or `false`.
>
> This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form
>   `"@[package:]type:name"`) or theme attribute (in the form
>   `"?[package:][type:]name"`) containing a value of this type.
>
> This is a private symbol.
>
> > **Related Methods**
> >
> > `setCounterEnabled(boolean)`
>
> From: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#attr_android.support.design:counterEnabled

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but read the question carefully, please. I already implemented it, but counters appear outside of the TextInputLayout, as they would with regular text fields. I need them to appear inside text fields, not outside. I'll edit the question to clarify it.